# How to host next.js app to firebase with the following project structure?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js, firebase-hosting

Here is project structure:

[image: project structure]

[image: app folder structure]

I have website written on next.js. In order to use next-i18next and sending email, there is src/app/server/server.js .

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const nextI18NextMiddleware = require("next-i18next/middleware");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const nextI18next = require("../i18n");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const nextApp = next({ dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" });
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  // parse application/json
  server.use(bodyParser.json());

  const sendMail = require("./sendMail");
  server.use("/api/v1/communicate", sendMail);

  server.use(nextI18NextMiddleware(nextI18next));

  server.get("*", (req, res) => handle(req, res));

  server.listen(port);
  console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

To host app on firebase I used firebase functions in src/functions/index.js:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const next = require("next");

var dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var app = next({ dev, conf: { distDir: "next" } });
var handle = app.getRequestHandler();

exports.next = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log("File: " + req.originalUrl); // log the page.js file that is being requested
  return app.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res));
});
```

In the root of project I have package.json:

```
{
  "name": "src",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "install": "yarn build-all",
    "next": "yarn build-firebase && cd \"src/app\" && yarn && yarn dev",
    "preserve": "yarn build-all",
    "serve": "firebase serve",
    "predeploy": "yarn build-all",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy",
    "build-all": "yarn build-next && yarn build-firebase",
    "build-next": "cd \"src/app\" && yarn && yarn build",
    "build-firebase": "cd \"src/functions\" && yarn"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  }
}
```

When I run command

```
yarn build-all
```

I have this output:

[image: command output1]

When I run command

```
firebase deploy --only functions:next
```

I have this output:

[image: command output2]

Currently, my problem is that I don't now how to deploy the app on firebase hosting.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything, that helps me to understand the problem. I would be very happy to hear at least some assumptions, that can help me to understand the problem.

Thank you, in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Question is pretty old, but if you're still wondering how to fix this issue, try to add this yarn script:

```
"ignore-engine": "yarn config set ignore-engines true"
```

And update your build-all cmd:

```
"build-all": "yarn ignore-engine && yarn build-next && yarn build-firebase"
```